# How can I conditionally style only the text in the selected item of a ComboBox?

Tags: wpf

I have a situation where I need to style the selected item in a ComboBox differently (make the text bold) when it is one of all except one value.  For example, in the drop-down box labelled "What is your favourite primary colour?" I would have four options: `No Preference`, `Red`, `Green`, and `Blue`.  The ComboBox items are just text with default styling, no images or anything else fancy, and are C# classes, not wrapped in ComboBoxItems.

When the user specifies a preference from the list, I want to highlight that choice by setting the text of the selected item *in the collapsed list* to be bold.  If the user chooses `No Preference`, the font weight should remain normal.

I have achieved a 90% solution by setting the FontWeight property on the ComboBox to Bold in a Style with a DataTrigger defined as `SelectedItem != No Preference`.  However, this styles all items in the ComboBox's list of items, including all those in the drop-down list.  I would like those items to *always* be displayed with a normal font weight.

Is this possible?

**Edit**

I have been trying @crazyarabian's method of styling the ComboBoxItem with a MultiTrigger.  The style definition is:

```
<Style x:Key="SelectedItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="ComboBoxItem.FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="ComboBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsNoPreferenceSelected,Mode=OneWay}" Value="False" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="ComboBoxItem.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and it is applied to a ComboBox in the following DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PrimaryColoursTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:PrimaryColoursViewModel}">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PrimaryColours}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPrimaryColour}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SelectedItemStyle}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Unfortunately, this kills WPF:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 8 : Cannot save value from target back to source. BindingExpression:Path=IsDropDownOpen; DataItem='ComboBox' (Name=''); target element is 'ToggleButton' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1') InvalidOperationException:'System.InvalidOperationException: Must have non-null value for 'Property'.
```

The application dies with a `NullReferenceException`, which is thrown after the InvalidOperationException above (or perhaps leads to it, I can't decipher the output).  The only thing I can think of that might be causing this is resolving the property in the binding in my second MultiTrigger condition, but I don't get any binding errors at all.  Here's the top of the stack trace in case that helps too:

```
InvalidOperationException:'System.InvalidOperationException: Must have non-null value for 'Property'.
   at System.Windows.Condition.Seal(ValueLookupType type)
   at System.Windows.ConditionCollection.Seal(ValueLookupType type)
   at System.Windows.MultiTrigger.Seal()
   at System.Windows.TriggerCollection.Seal()
   at System.Windows.Style.Seal()
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle, Style& styleCache)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.ApplyItemContainerStyle(DependencyObject container, Object item)
```

Comment: With owner draw controls, anything is possible. It's a pain though, since you have to reproduce all the different states that Windows automatically does for you.

Comment: Eeek, that sounds pretty heavyweight!  I was hoping for a nice templating-type solution or something...

Comment: YourWish == MyCommand. Don't you dare try owner-draw. ;)

Comment: Additionally, I have found that removing the IsNoPreferenceSelected condition mentioned in my edit a) stops the app crashing :-), and b) only highlights the selected item in the list of all items and not in the collapsed ComboBox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to get into anything as despicable as owner-draw-- we are talking about *WPF* here, not WinForms. In WinForms, your only solution was to write more code. In WPF, we can solve this problem with a few very simple custom templates. For this example, I used [Kaxaml](http://kaxaml.com/), a free light-weight XAML editor. No code-behind was required. **Kaxaml** comes packed with a bunch of "starter" styles called *Simple Styles*. I used the *ComboBox Simple Style* and made modifications from that. So although this looks like a lot of XAML, I really just started with the boilerplate one and added a couple lines.

You can probably think of more elegant ways of triggering the font weight change; I used `SelectedIndex`.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Page.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectionBoxTextTemplate">
         <TextBlock FontWeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}, Path=FontWeight}" Text="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
               x:Name="Border"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               Background="#C0C0C0"
               BorderBrush="#404040"
               BorderThickness="1"
               CornerRadius="2"/>
            <Border
               Grid.Column="0"
               Margin="1"
               Background="#FFFFFF"
               BorderBrush="#404040"
               BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
               CornerRadius="2,0,0,2"/>
            <Path
               x:Name="Arrow"
               Grid.Column="1"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"
               Fill="#404040"/>
         </Grid>
         <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
               <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#808080"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
               <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#E0E0E0"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
               <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
               <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#AAAAAA"/>
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
               <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="#888888"/>
            </Trigger>
         </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
      <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
         <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
         <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
         <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
         <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
         <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
         <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
         <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                  <Grid>
                     <ToggleButton
                        Name="ToggleButton"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        Focusable="false"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}">
                     </ToggleButton>
                     <ContentPresenter
                        Name="ContentSite"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SelectionBoxTextTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                     <TextBox
                        x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Focusable="False"
                        IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                        Style="{x:Null}"
                        Visibility="Hidden"/>
                     <Popup
                        Name="Popup"
                        AllowsTransparency="True"
                        Focusable="False"
                        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        Placement="Bottom"
                        PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid
                           Name="DropDown"
                           MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                           MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                           SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                           <Border
                              x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                              Background="#FFFFFF"
                              BorderBrush="#888888"
                              BorderThickness="1"/>
                           <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                              <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"/>
                           </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                     </Popup>
                  </Grid>
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" SourceName="Popup" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="3">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                     </Trigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
      <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
         <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
         <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
         <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                  <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                     <ContentPresenter/>
                  </Border>
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#DDDDDD"/>
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                     </Trigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </Page.Resources>
   <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="What is your favorite primary colour?"/>
      <ComboBox Width="150" SelectedIndex="0">
         <ComboBoxItem>No Preference</ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem>Red</ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem>Green</ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem>Blue</ComboBoxItem>
      </ComboBox>
   </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

I used the `ContentTemplate` property of the `ContentPresenter` in `ComboBox` to add a custom data template (`SelectionBoxTextTemplate`). That `TextBlock` grabs its `FontWeight` from an ancestor combo-box. I then added a template for the individual items, that forces them to normal font weight. This got the result you were looking for:

[image]

Comment: But doesn't this also over-ride (and/or hard-code) the default style of the ComboBox?  The ComboBox in your example screenshot, whilst it displays the behaviour I'm after, does not look like a standard Windows ComboBox.

Comment: As I previously mentioned, I started from the "Simple Styles" combo-box that comes with Kaxaml. If you take the Windows default style as your starting point, and make the same changes, you will end up with the right result. Try using this template as your starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: But if I do that, won't it hard-code the (e.g.) Windows 7 style?  Or will the theming magic still kick in and make it look correct for Windows XP users too?

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply your trigger to the ComboBoxItem itself. Unless you've changed the behavior of the ComboBox, all items are displayed within containers (which are used to apply styles and templates) and the default container used by a ComboBox is a ComboBoxItem.

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You'll need to add your existing triggers to compensate for not bolding the selection when it is No Preference.

Comment: My understanding is that multiple triggers == logical OR, not logical AND (which is obtained by combining multiple properties into one trigger).  Given that my trigger is a DataTrigger and yours is a Property Trigger, I think the only way to combine these to use both triggers (and so get a logical OR when in fact I want an AND).

Comment: Furthermore, the ComboBox resides in a DataTemplate which is bound to a ViewModel class.  See the line in the question above about the ComboBox items being C# classes and not ComboBoxItems.  I tried applying the style to {x:Type ComboBoxItem} with no luck - all the bold text disappeared.

Comment: @alastairs whenever you add items to an ItemsControl, they are automatically wrapped by a wrapper class; in the case of ComboBox it is ComboBoxItem by default unless you've changed that behavior. The fact that your triggers are now working against a ComboBoxItem does not mean that the container itself is a different object, it just means that for some reason the triggers aren't working. I think you need to use one DataTrigger with a MultiBinding and appropriate converter.

Comment: @alastairs this is a good resource on the ItemsControl: http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/03/25/itemscontrol-i-is-for-item-container/

Comment: Thanks for the update, and the link. It was an interesting read. I've updated my question with my experiments into styling the ComboBoxItem with a MultiTrigger.

Answer (score -4):

I'm not an expert on WPF, but in Windows Forms the answer is called "OwnerDraw." This means that your code is responsible for drawing the control, instead of relying on the default behavior. When you're drawing it yourself, you can apply any style you want - including the ability to draw different items with different styles.

I did a quick web search for "combobox ownerdraw" and got over 1,000,000 hits. You're not the only one that needs to do this, so you're sure to find a decent tutorial pretty quickly.